# Smooth out rigging?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm still a little new to rigging. I want to try and make this tail curve a little smoother and not look like a finger. I looked up tutorials, but all I could find was to use bendy bones. However, Since this is going to be exported to unity, I can't really use those.

so, I'm wondering if it's possible to make this tail curve smoother using standard bones. perhaps a better way of weight painting or something?

(i'm using blender 2.93 as well btw)
Blender File here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/352uwxp8ka627pes1rcn2/Tail-Armature.blend?rlkey=b8cfmmhbuqsqzjz15ww88gur0&dl=0
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it have enough horizontal subdivisions? I've given a try and it works fine for me: https://zupimages.net/up/23/30/ok92.jpg but maybe share your file?

Comment: It does have Quad faces. I placed a link to the blender file with the tail in the dropbox link. @moonboots

Comment: I meant maybe make your tail more low-poly but if you need to use your object in a game engine you may need it to be high-poly enough to have a smooth outline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best is to subdivide the bones and parent again.

You could try to smooth the weights (in *Weight Paint* mode, select a vertex group, *Weights > Smooth*, and in the *Operator Box* increase the *Iterations* up to 50 or whatever value), but it will make the control a bit more complicated. Also don't forget to enable the *Preserve Volume* option in the *Armature* modifier:

[image]

Before/After:

[image]